# Retrofit doesn't receive response on request

Tags: java, android, rx-java, retrofit2

I have an api for for requesting some json-data from server. For simplifying  my code I wrapped my api in RxJava Single. Also I have a list with necessary entities ids, which I need to save. I iterate this list, take one id and try to receive data by it. It works for several entities, but on one retrofit not received response. We checked it on backend and server sends response. Also, it not depended from id of entity.
My code is looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comparisonResult.getNew().size(); i++) {
    ApiMessageCompareData newMessage = comparisonResult.getNew().get(i);

    ApiMessage newMessage = getItemMessage(newMessage.getMessageId())
        .doOnError(t -> {
            String errorMessage = t.getMessage() + " " + newMessage.getMessageId();
            Log.e("Remote2LocalMessage", errorMessage, t);
        }).blockingGet();

    /// handle received message
}
```

I need to handle this entities one-by-one, that is why I using `blockingGet()`.

Here is api call:

```
public Single<ApiMessage> getItemMessage(long id) {
    return RetrofitClient.getInstance()
            .getInspectionsService()
            .getItemMessage(id)
            .flatMap(this::handleResultAndMap);
}
```

I receive response from api and return new Single with error or success && data:

```
protected <T> Single<T> handleResultAndMap(Response<T> response) {
    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
        return Single.create(emitter -> emitter.onSuccess(response.body()));
    } else {
        String message = "Error on server";
        return Single.create(emitter -> emitter.onError(new Exception(message)));
    }
}
```

My api method looks like this:

```
@GET("SomeUrl")
Single<Response<ApiMessage>> getItemMessage(
        @Query("id") long id
);
```

Have anybody an ideas: what it can be?

**UPD**

In my log, I have this one:

```
2019-06-27 16:35:49.097 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: --> GET http://SomeUrl?id=161
2019-06-27 16:35:49.097 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: --> END GET
```

If Retrofit receives response, then it shows this log after first one:

```
2019-06-27 16:35:48.967 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK http://SomeUrl?id=431 (82ms)
2019-06-27 16:35:48.967 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: <headers>
2019-06-27 16:35:48.968 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: <response-body>
2019-06-27 16:35:48.968 1662-3624/com.pckgname D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (146-byte body)
```

Comment: Do you have any error or stacktrace in the logcat?

Comment: @JaimeSuárez, I added logs, which I see in logs